# QTime or QTimer wait for timeout

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm writting a Qt application, and I have a four hour loop (in a seperate thread).  In that four hour loop, I have to:

1. do stuff with the serial port;
2. wait a fixed period of time;
3. do some more stuff with the serial port;
4. wait an arbitrary amount of time.
5. when 500ms have past, do more stuff;
6. Go to 1. and repeat for four hours.

Currently, my method of doing this is really bad, and crashes some computers.  I have a whole bunch of code, but the following snippet basically shows the problem.  The CPU goes to ~100% and eventually can crash the computer.

```
 void CRelayduinoUserControl::wait(int timeMS)
{
    int curTime = loopTimer->elapsed();
    while(loopTimer->elapsed() < curTime + timeMS);
}
```

I need to somehow wait for a particular amount of time to pass before continuing on with the program.  Is there some function which will just wait for some arbitrary period of time while keeping all the timers going?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996706/qt-c-wait-till-specific-time-to-execute-function/14144614#14144614

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sleep in QT, use [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html).  Just connect the timeout signal from the timer to the slot that contains the code you want to do every x amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I know about the sleep() function; the problem is that when I sleep, the timers stop counting.

Comment: The QTimer is your timer. Why do you need to keep some other timer running?

Comment: Because I need to do something every 500ms for four hours in a seperate thread.  If I sleep, the timers stop...

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should use the signal/slot mechanism in spite of waiting inside a while. Code could be something like that:

```
#define STATE_1 0x01
#define STATE_2 0x02
#define STATE_3 0x03
.....
QTimer * timer  = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),SLOT(timerSlot()));
int state = STATE_1 ;
timer->timerSlot()
.... 


void timerSlot() { 
  switch(state) {
    case STATE_1:
      // do stuff with the serial port
      state = STATE_2;
      timer->start(time_to_wait_in_ms);
      break;
    case STATE_2:
      // do more stuff with the serial port
      state = STATE_3;
      timer->start(500);
      break; 
    case STATE_3:
      // do more stuff 
      state = STATE_1;
      timer->start(1000*60*60*4);
      break; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  There are a couple of issues I have though; my timer(s) would be running in a new thread and I don't know how to keep that thread waiting for a signal without it exiting.  I'm thinking of using a qEventLoop to solve this.  Also, the code you provided, while it's waiting for the 4 hour timeout, it won't actually receive any other signals (like the 500ms timeout).

Comment: Well, you can easily modify it with another Timer to wait for 500 ms timeout while you are in the 4h wait. IMO is the simpliest approach, rather than using another thread.

Comment: The beauty of a QThread is that it won't exit until you call `thread->exit()`. A default QThread implementation spins an event loop in its `run()` method. This event loop will be active until you exit from it. The code, when it's waiting for a timeout, will in fact receive signals and events - it's asynchronous, after all: it executes quickly a bit of its code then returns to the event loop when it exits `timerSlot()`.